# Cannot load css and images after creating another branch

Tags: html, css, branch

I created a new bash branch from the main branch and split the html file into three parts:

top and bottom html are in templates directory;
middle html is in content directory;

When I put them together in another directory called docs, the page won't load the css and pictures (css and pictures are in docs directory -> sub directory css and img)

I tried  or

but they won't load it

Comment: Perhaps you should double check the relative paths

Comment: What does the browser console give you? 404s? 403s? Are the files even present in the page source?

Comment: I was able to fix this by checking the path of it. Thanks